# split spreadsheet/excel file into multiple csv files with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: vba, excel, utf-8, export-to-csv

The below code successfully converts big excel files in to csv files with the specified number of rows.
How ever I want the output file to be UTF-8 encoded CSV files.

How to add UTF-8 code to below, I would like to combine the below splitting file code with UTF-8 conversion code

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
  Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  Dim RangeOfHeader As Range        'data (range) of header row
  Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
  Dim RowsInFile                    'how many rows (incl. header) in new files?
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Initialize data
  Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  WorkbookCounter = 1
  RowsInFile = 5                   'as your example, just 10 rows per file

  'Copy the data of the first row (header)
  Set RangeOfHeader = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(1, NumOfColumns))

  For p = 2 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile - 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    'Paste the header row in new file
    RangeOfHeader.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    'Paste the chunk of rows for this file
    Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 2, NumOfColumns))
    RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

    'Save the new workbook, and close it
    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4) & "_v" & WorkbookCounter & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    wb.Close True

    'Increment file counter
    WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
  Next p

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this VBA? Please add a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: yes vba macro code, can you help

Comment: No sorry. But with the correct tags you are more likely to get help.

Comment: That's some elegant VBA code if there ever was.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ADODB library Stream object. The below code uses early binding so don't forget to tick the relevant MS ActiveX Data Object reference accordingly before running.

```
Sub saveAsUTF8()
    Dim myStream As ADODB.Stream
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim curRow As String
    Dim curRowRng As Range
    Dim curCell As Range

    Set myStream = New ADODB.Stream

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With myStream
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open

        For Each curRowRng In ws.UsedRange.Rows
            curRow = ""
            For Each curCell In curRowRng.Cells
                curRow = curRow & "," & curCell.Value
            Next curCell
            curRow = Right(curRow, Len(curRow) - 1)
            .WriteText curRow, adWriteLine
        Next curRowRng

        'CHANGE TO YOU DESTINATION DIRECTORY
        .SaveToFile "YOUR_PATH\utf8file.csv", adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine the splitting code and UTF-8 Conversion code
Please help me in combining both the codes

Comment: Have you tried and run the code I have provided? if so - can you confirm what else you need compare to what it already does?

Comment: I dont need to compare "I need to COMBINE my code (Splitting files) with your code of UTF -8 conversion and also want to make this dynamic. As currently file name is harcoded in the code, it should prompt/browse for the file name